# No envía datos ingresados en POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mvc

Tengo un problema con el envio de datos por POST, estoy realizando una aplicacion php con mvc puro y JavaScript (jQuery), ahora bien, estoy tratando de realizar un formulario el cual se encuentra en un **DIV** de una pagina principal, al momento de enviar el formulario deseo, que envie a un *controlador* ejemplo: **Empresa** y un *metodo* ejemplo **guardarEmpresa**, y ahí recoger los valores: en este momento solo tengo un campo empresa.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                </div>
<!-- Aquí debería mostrarme la empresa que envíe por POST -->

<div class="col-9" style="background-color:#FFFF;" id="objeto"></div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="formulario" action="Empresa/guardarEmpresa" method="POST" >
                        <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" placeholder="ingrese empresa">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"  value="Guardar">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                </div>
            </div>
         <body>
```

Y tengo este Jquery:

```js
jQuery(function($){

    var formulario = $('#formulario');


    formulario.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(event.currentTarget);

        var destinationLocation = $target.attr('action');
        if (destinationLocation !== '#') {
            $('#objeto').load(
                destinationLocation
            );
        }
    });

});
```

que actualmente funciona, osea, va al controlador se ubica en el metodo y si escribo dentro del mismo:

```html
class empresa{
  public function guardarEmpresa(){
    echo "Llegas hasta acá y sin cargar me muestras este mensaje en el      div";
  }
}
```

redirige cargando el **echo** del mensaje, y lo coloca en el **div**

```
<div class="col-9" style="background-color:#FFFF;" id="objeto"></div>
```

Pero cuando envío datos no los agarra en el metodo, osea no llegan los datos.

$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
Resultado **Nada**

Le hago un var_dump a $_POST

Resultado **Array()**

Agradezco me puedan ayudar, ya lo hice sin el jquery (de la forma natural), me redirige la pagina y ahí si agarra los post. pero eso no lo necesito, necesito que todo lo maneje dentro del div.

Muchas gracias al que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: En tu código, ¿dónde ocurre el envío que hace Ajax hacia el servidor? No lo veo por ningún lado. Y tu código en ese sentido es poco convencional. ¿Puedes explicarlo, indicando **dónde** según tú se envían los datos? Y, por qué en el action no hay una extensión de archivo PHP, ¿estás usando URLs amigables o algo por el estilo? ¿Las redirecciones funcionan bien en ese caso... las has probado?

Comment: Estás en lo correcto @A.Cedano son URL amigables, lo que deseo es que con el jquery que tengo, envíe los datos por post lleguen al controlador y metodo, lo guarde en una variable **$empresa = $_POST['empresa'] y si le hago un echo a la variable, no me abrá otra página, sino que lo coloqué dentro del <div> actualmente funciona, si hago un echo en el metodo lo retorna, pero no la variable que agarro por $_POST; lo unico que recibo dentro del div es Notice: Undefined index: empresa in C:\xampp\htdocs\bedsheet\app\controladores\archivo.php on line 28

Comment: Pero, pregunto de nuevo, porque no lo veo... ¿en qué parte del código Javascript haces el POST y qué datos pasas en dicho POST? ¿Me puedes indicar en qué líneas del código lo haces....? No lo veo

Comment: No he sabido adicionarle al script jquery que tengo, el llamado al POST, para que los envíe al metodo y lo pueda imprimir en el div con la linea **$('#objeto').load(
                destinationLocation
            );** ese .load hace que me muestre en el <div>  cualquier error o cualquier **echo** que coloque en el metodo sin que me lo muestre en otra pagina; por el momento desearia que lo que escriba en empresa lo guarde en una variable y lo imprima en el <div>, sé que no está por el momento el llamado ajax a los datos POST, pero no sé en donde colocarlo en mi script sin que se pireda nada.

Comment: Lee la respuesta de @AlbertoSiurob, ahí él explica cómo hacer el POST vía Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy raro tu código, no estas usando AJAX, estás usando el comportamiento natural de un `<form>`

Te voy a dejar unas recomendaciones sin necesidad de utilizar el `<form>` a menos que utlices CSS con selectores directos a tag o acciones complejas con JS.

**TU HTML**

```
<div class="col-9" style="background-color:#FFFF;" id="objeto"></div>
<div class="col-6">
    <input type="text" id="empresa" placeholder="ingrese empresa">
    <input type="button" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="Cargar Excel">
</div>
<div class="col"></div>
```

Como el DOM ya sabe que tiene que recoger sólo un valor, entonces no necesitamos el formulario, sólo tener en memoria la empresa y la ruta donde se procesará. Quité el formulario, y le puse un ID al botón de enviar

**TU JAVASCRIPT**

```
//Cuando cargue el DOM ( función ready que tu tenías )
$( () => {

    /*Creamos una función que esté escuchando el evento 
    click del botón enviar y pasamos unas instrucciones*/
    $( document ).on( 'click', '#enviar', function(){

        //Recogemos el valor de la empresa
        let empresa = $('#empresa').val();

        //Validamos que hayan escrito algo
        if( empresa.trim() != '' ){

            //Lanzamos una petición AJAX

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Empresa/guardarEmpresa',
                data: { empresa },
                success: function( respuesta ){

                    /*Cuando el backend procese la solicitud regresará algo, 
                    lo almacenamos en respuesta*/

                    //Ahora esa respuesta la ponemos en el div
                    $('#objeto').html( respuesta )
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**TU PHP**

```
<?php
class Empresa{

    public function guardarEmpresa( $valor ){
      //Todo lo que tengas que hace con ese valor
      return "La información para el DIV";
    }
}

//Recuperas el valor que llegó por POST, en realidad
//El superarreglo $_REQUEST engloba $_POST y $_GET
$valor = $_REQUEST['empresa'];

//Instanciamos un objeto de empresa
$empresa = new Empresa();

//regresamos al front lo que procesó la función
echo $empresa->guardarEmpresa( $valor );
?>
```

No entiendo que haga tu código de PHP, de hecho no se por qué estas recibiendo los valores en la misma clase ( o lo estoy imaginando, quizá tenga otra esctructura ) si lo tienes todo junto te recomendaría lo separaras para una mejor mantenibilidad a largo plazo.

Si no te sirve mucho el código de PHP, solo puedes usar `$_REQUEST['empresa']` o `$_POST['empresa']` para recuperar lo enviado

Espero te puedas guiar

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder prontamente, el <form> tendría más campos, los eliminé por dejar el codigo más limpio, pero hay más; entonces creo que si o si tendría que haber las etiquetas <form> el action que está dentro es muy importante para lo que hago, porqué es el que el jQuery con la funcion : var destinationLocation = $target.attr('action'); por que pienso utilizar el script en más partes y no creo que me sirva estar colocando script para form que cree, como dije anteriormente, es mvc puro osea existen URL **empresa/guardarempresa** controlador y metodo.

Comment: Ahora dentro del metodo guardaempresa, lo que deseo es que si coloco $_POST['empresa']; está me la ponga en DIV y abra otra pagina nueva.